# Clojure: how to make a leiningen build reproducible?

Tags: jar, clojure, jvm

#### Introduction

As stated on [reproducible-builds.org](https://reproducible-builds.org/), it's a best-practice to be able to produce a build which can be re-created when given equal source code by anyone on any machine/os, at any time. How can I achieve this with a Clojure/Leiningen environment?

#### Example

Very basic example usage of creating a project and building a `.jar` file with Leiningen:

```sh
lein new app hello
cd hello
lein uberjar
sha256sum target/uberjar/hello-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

This outputs a certain sha256 hash, which contains non-determinism inside the `.jar` file. If you immediately re-run the build without changing any source files the checksum hash will be different anyway:

```sh
lein uberjar
sha256sum target/uberjar/hello-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

#### Question

How can I create a `.jar` file which results in the same checksum hash when run again, also for example on a different linux distro, somewhere in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a package available for just this: **[strip-nondeterminism](https://salsa.debian.org/reproducible-builds/strip-nondeterminism)**, it supports `.jar` files as well. It's available in [debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/strip-nondeterminism) and [ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/strip-nondeterminism) (and probably other debian-based distro's), but you can always use it from source.

Install (debian/ubuntu/etc.):

```sh
sudo apt install strip-nondeterminism
```

Build:

```sh
lein uberjar
strip-nondeterminism -t jar target/uberjar/hello-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
sha256sum target/uberjar/hello-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

When the build is ran multiple times, this outputs the same checksum hash. It resets all file timestamps to a static value.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Jar file is not deterministic, but its content is. Try

```
unzip -c hello-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar | md5sum
```

Comment: In case you are wondering "why the Jar file itself is not deterministic?": Jar files are Zip files which themselves contains metadata including timestamps of the compressed files inside, so the Jar file itself changes a little bit between runs of `lein uberjar`, but the (compressed) file contents do not.

Comment: Can't a Jar (or zip) file be made deterministic? For example by setting all the metadata or file timestamps to predictable static values?